# Android Age Spinner Item

Tags: android

Is it possible to build a for loop that goes to 100 to populate an Android spinner? As opposed to manually adding to the ArrayList.

Something like the below:

```
List<Integer> age = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    age.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. What makes you think this would not be possible? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, besides the missing bottom bracket, that's very possible. If you need it to populate it with numbers from 1 to 100 though, I'd change the condition to: `i <= 100`.

Comment: P.S You should pass the type parameter in List, <Integer> (in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to programmatically populate your `ArrayList`; you just need to use an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) like this:

```
List age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    age.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
         this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, age);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

yes of coures you can use...

Like this --

```
List age = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
age.add(i);
}]
```

now you have to use Array\adapter-

```
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> sa= new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
     this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, age);
   sa.setDropDownViewResource(       
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

    Spinner s= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        s.setAdapter(sa);
```